# Education background and last employment for the spouse in family application (DS 160)

Tags: b1-b2-visas, applications, family, spouses

In family application (DS 160) the education background and last employment for the spouse is not required. Is it OK that there is no section for the spouse regarding education background and the employment within 5 years? Or did I make a mistake?

Thank you in advance.

Answer (score 1):

Yes, different profiles get different questions. For example, children and women from low-risk countries will not get the educational background and previous employment question. On the other hand, men (regardless of nationality) and women from high-risk countries do get that question.

Source: Filled up a few dummy forms to see what sort of questions are asked for different profiles.

Answer (score 0):

While the system lets you create a family or group application after completing the first application, every person submits a separate form which has their details. You would not be able to submit the application if you didn't complete a mandatory question.

Resource: [DS-160 Frequently Asked Questions](https://travel.state.gov/content/travel/en/us-visas/visa-information-resources/forms/ds-160-online-nonimmigrant-visa-application/ds-160-faqs.html)